# Python GTK3 keyboard accelerators

Tags: application-development, gtk3, python3

I'm working on creating an application for Ubuntu using Python3 and Gtk3.

I'm trying to add keyboard accelerators to the program but unfortunately I keep running into problems.

This is my code atm:

```
#! /bin/python

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class DeSedit(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="DeSedit")

        self.set_default_size(550, 350)

        # FileChooserDialog - Open File
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Select file to be opened", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        # keyboard shortcuts
        accel = Gtk.AccelGroup()
        self.add_accel_group(accel)
        self.add_accelerator(dialog, "<Control>o", signal="open")

        def add_accelerator(self, widget, accelerator, signal="activate"):
            """ adds <Control>o as accelerator for open-file dialog """
            if accelerator is not None:
                key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
            widget.add_accelelator(signal, accel, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
            print("works")

        # grid to organize widgets
        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(self.box)
        # text view
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textview.set_wrap_mode(True)
        # scroll bar
        scrollwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrollwindow.add(self.textview)

        self.box.pack_start(scrollwindow, True, True, 0)


window = DeSedit()  # create DeSedit object
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I get this error:

```
File "file.py", line 41, in 
    window = DeSedit()  # create DeSedit object
  File "file.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.add_accelerator(self.dialog, "o", signal="open")
TypeError: add_accelerator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'signal'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely you following a PyGtk **2** [guide](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-WidgetAccelerators.html) when trying to implement this: According to the GTK 3 documentation there is no function named `gtk_window_add_accelerator`, but there is a function named `gtk_accel_group_connect` that looks like its going to get the job done. When working with GTK documentation it's usually 80% gut feeling and 20% checking the docs to seen if your right. Don't expect any fancy tutorials or guides (you'll be disappointed most of the time)…

Anyway: Looking at the [`gtk_accel_group_connect`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accel-group-connect) documentation, we see these parameters: `accel_group`, `accel_key`, `accel_mods`, `accel_flags` and `closure`.

So how to call this function from Python? Let's do this step by step:

1. Since we're in Python (object-oriented language) we can expect the `accel_group` parameter to be implicit as it's the first parameter and a reference to the object we're trying to modify.
2. The next parameter (`accel_key`) is more tricky: It's an integer and the documentation just tells us *key value of the accelerator* which basically means *figure out yourself how to find the accelerator key value*. Fortunately some quick search reveals the function [`gdk_keyval_from_name`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Keyboard-Handling.html#gdk-keyval-from-name) which seems to do what we want. (And calling `Gdk.keyval_from_name('O')` actually returns the right result.)
3. Next is the parameter `accel_mods`: By clicking on its type ([`GdkModifierType`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkModifierType)) we get a nice listing of all the possible modifier types. As you wanted to use the `<Control>` modifier we can just use `Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK` and move on.
4. `accel_flags` also has a clickable type ([`GtkAccelFlags`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#GtkAccelFlags)) and opening its description reveals that none of these parameters are needed so we may safely use `0` for this paramter.
5. Finally we're at the last parameter (`closure`): Since `closure` is just a fancy word for callback (something that should be called when something happens) we can just use the fact that the Python GTK bindings abstract closures for us and and pass some callable function here that gets called whenever `<Control>O` was pressed.

In context the code now looks like this (verified to be working):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class DeSedit(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="DeSedit")

        self.set_default_size(550, 350)

        # FileChooserDialog - Open File
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Select file to be opened", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        # keyboard shortcuts
        accel = Gtk.AccelGroup()
        accel.connect(Gdk.keyval_from_name('O'), Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK, 0, self.on_accel_pressed)
        self.add_accel_group(accel)

        # grid to organize widgets
        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(self.box)
        # text view
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textview.set_wrap_mode(True)
        # scroll bar
        scrollwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrollwindow.add(self.textview)

        self.box.pack_start(scrollwindow, True, True, 0)

    def on_accel_pressed(self, *args):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Select file to be opened", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        dialog.show()


window = DeSedit()  # create DeSedit object
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
```

Hope this gets you started with GTK+3!